# How to count multiple dates in php array

Tags: php, arrays

How I can count same values in the Array. I have read about the **array_count_values()** but this function can only count  **Integer or String values** but My problem is that I want to count same dates in the Array, How can I count the same dates in the Array.

I have tried this array_count_values() but this gives me this error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!

Filename: controllers/Dashboard.php

Line Number: 72

Backtrace:

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/blink_app/application/controllers/Dashboard.php
Line: 72
Function: array_count_values

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/blink_app/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

And Here Is my Array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [saloon_staff_id] => 1
            [users_id] => 5
            [ref_id] => 1
            [date] => 2017-11-02
            [time_from] => 12:15:00
            [time_to] => 13:30:00
            [appointment_status] => 2017-11-23
            [saloon_services_id] => 3
            [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
            [phone_number] => 098098098
            [email] => SalmanIq@facebook.com
            [appointments_enabled] => 1
            [role_in_saloon] => Owner
            [name] => Salman Iqbal
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [saloon_staff_id] => 2
            [users_id] => 6
            [ref_id] => 2
            [date] => 2017-11-02
            [time_from] => 04:30:00
            [time_to] => 05:00:00
            [appointment_status] => 2017-11-25
            [saloon_services_id] => 2
            [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
            [phone_number] => 98790809809
            [email] => alludin@gmail.com
            [appointments_enabled] => 1
            [role_in_saloon] => No Access
            [name] => Alludin 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [saloon_staff_id] => 1
            [users_id] => 7
            [ref_id] => 3
            [date] => 2017-11-04
            [time_from] => 03:00:00
            [time_to] => 03:30:00
            [appointment_status] => 2017-11-28
            [saloon_services_id] => 2
            [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
            [phone_number] => 098098098
            [email] => SalmanIq@facebook.com
            [appointments_enabled] => 1
            [role_in_saloon] => Owner
            [name] => Salman Iqbal
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [saloon_staff_id] => 3
            [users_id] => 7
            [ref_id] => 4
            [date] => 2017-11-28
            [time_from] => 01:00:00
            [time_to] => 02:00:00
            [appointment_status] => 2017-11-28
            [saloon_services_id] => 1
            [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
            [phone_number] => 9080809
            [email] => mubi@yahoo.com
            [appointments_enabled] => 0
            [role_in_saloon] => Owner
            [name] => mubassir
        )

)
```

Any Help Will be Appreciated.

Comment: Show more.  Your question is very incomplete.  Every time you post show exactly what you've tried, offer sample input, and your expected output... EVERY TIME.  Your question is justifiably closable for a variety of reasons.  Please edit your question before the downvotes start rolling in.

Comment: I was about to downvote but sometimes it make sense to help people on boarding rather making them scared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a column out of multi-dimensional array on which you want to do aggregation / count.

```
<?php

$array = [['name' => 'foo', 'date' => '2017-11-28'], ['name' => 'bar', 'date' => '2017-11-29'], ['name' => 'baz', 'date' => '2017-11-28']];

$dates = array_column($array, 'date'); // here 1st param is the array
```

This will give you

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2017-11-28
    [1] => 2017-11-29
    [2] => 2017-11-28
)
```

Now you can call `array_count_values` like:

```
print_r(array_count_values($dates));

Array
(
    [2017-11-28] => 2
    [2017-11-29] => 1
)
```

Comment: How can i convert it multi-dimensional array?

Comment: it also gives me this error. Message: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Comment: Can you paste your code in the question so that i can see whats happening

Comment: @SalmanIqbal How can i convert it multi-dimensional array? Please explain more

Comment: Sorry my bad ! `array_column` first param is array second is the name of column. PHP :D

Comment: Your answer is very helpful i got this arary. Array
(
    [2017-11-23] => 1
    [2017-11-25] => 1
    [2017-11-28] => 2
)

Comment: How i will access this values

Comment: every time it will change from database

Comment: you will access from your array keys. Now this is out of scope of this question. If you are having trouble accessing data from database, Kindly come up with a new question and make sure you post your code also if you want people to understand your problem correctly.